# Bump and Normal Map node changes color of my Image Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normal-map, shader-nodes, bump

I tried to use apples as a texture and add to it a bit of depth. But after adding bump or normal map it changes color to black and white. How can I keep the color?

[image]

Comment: you need to plug it into the Base Color input

Comment: I tried it now but color changed just to  blue :( https://ibb.co/Kx6Wnwz

Comment: Plug the image into the Base color, _as well_.. but not through the _Bump_ node, for that branch.

Comment: It worked, thank you!